# Custom radical sign with plain XeTeX

Tags: fonts, symbols, xetex, math-operators, truetype

I would like to use Cambria Math font in mathematical equation, and I have a simple problem here. plain TeX uses many symbols for the root sign, so it can use the proper one depending on context, however the Unicode have only one (or maybe two) that is capable to replace big roots:
If the 3. family is set to Cambria Math, the line `` \def\sqrt{\XeTeXradical 3 `\⎷} `` does not produces the root sign at the proper place for example `$\sqrt{a\over b}$`.
How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `` `\⎷ `` is causing you trouble. Use the Unicode code point for the sqrt radical instead:

```
\font\x="Cambria Math:script=MATH" at 10pt
\textfont1=\x\textfont2=\x\textfont3=\x
\def\sqrt{\XeTeXradical 3 "0221A}
$$
\sqrt{1\over 2}
$$
\bye
```

Comment: You're right, thanks! Why is that happens though?

Comment: The symbol you used is U+23B7 "RADICAL SYMBOL BOTTOM", but you want U+221A "SQUARE ROOT". You could use ``\√` if you wished.

Comment: OpenType math fonts map internally the bigger glyphs to the regular one that has a Unicode code, the engine would then select the appropriately sized glyph according to context. The symbol you used exits for different use models and not directly utilized by OpenType math fonts (it is used usually for plain text mathematics).